# Are Ito Integrals adapted to the Brownian Motion Filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Give a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}_t, P)$, we could define a 1-dim Brownian motion $W_t$ adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_t$ with its own filtration $\mathcal{F}_t^W$. For the new process defined by the ito integral 
$$Y_t = \int_0^t X_s dW_s$$
What general properties we need on $X_t \in L^2(\Omega,\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_t, P)$ in order to say $Y_t$ is adapted to the Brownian motion filtration $\mathcal{F}_t^W$?

$X_t$ itself is adapted to  $\mathcal{F}_t^W$ is enough, but can we get more general conditions?

For example, is it true if $X_t$ is the solution of the SODE
$$dX_t = a(t, X_t) dt + b dW_t?$$

Comment: A strong solution of the SDE at the bottom of your question is, by definition, adapted.

Comment: Usually the Ito integral is only *defined* for processes which are already adapted.  So if you want to integrate a process which is not adapted, you need a new definition of the integral.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. From definition of Ito integral. $X_t$ is adapted to $\{F_t\}$, $W_t$ is also adapted to $\{F_t\}$, but is it true that $X_t$ is adapted to $F_t^W$?

Comment: @Xiao : no it is not always the case, take for example the filtration generated by a 2-d Brownian motion $(W^1,W^2)$, then the  stochastic integral $\int_0^t W^1_sdW^2_s$ is not adapted to the filtration generated by $W^2$. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge In your example, I don't think you assume $W^1$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}^{W^2}_t$.

Comment: @Xiao : yeah this the counterexample you where looking for, unless I misunderstood your comment. Best regards