# Are Ito Integrals adapted to the Brownian Motion Filtration 2

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have a question regarding that topic:
[Are Ito Integrals adapted to the Brownian Motion Filtration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720498/are-ito-integrals-adapted-to-the-brownian-motion-filtration).

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_t,P)$, we could define a 1-dim Brownian motion $W_t$ adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_t)_t$ with its own filtration $\mathcal{F}_t^W$. $X$ an $(\mathcal{F}_t)_t$-adapted process. For the new process defined by the ito integral
$Y_t=\int_0^t X_s dW_s$,
is it enough for $Y_t$ to be $\mathcal{F}_t^W$-adapted that $X_s\neq 0$, $s\in [0,t]$ a.s.? Or is there also a counterexample?

Comment: Why would you expect that $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}^W$-adapted if the integrand is not adapted to this filtration...?

Comment: I thought, that the filtration of $X$ is somehow simple if there is $X^{-1}$..

Comment: No... consider for instance an independent random variable $Z$ and set $X_t := Z$, $$\mathcal{F}_t := \sigma(W_s; s \leq t, Z).$$ Then $Y_t = Z W_t$ is not adapted to $\mathcal{F}^W$.

Comment: Oh, I understand... but at the following point I am still unsure: If $X$ is $\mathcal{F}^W$-adapted, then $Y$ is also $\mathcal{F}^W$-adapted, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_t^Y \subseteq \mathcal{F}_t^W$. Assume again $X_s\neq 0$, $s\geq 0$ a.s. Is it right that $\mathcal{F}_t^Y= \mathcal{F}_t^W$ holds for every $t \geq 0$? We have that $dY_t=X_t dW_t$ and so with our assumption we get $dW_t=X_t^{-1} dY_t$. Is that enough for showing $\mathcal{F}_t^W \subseteq \mathcal{F}_t^Y$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you or does anybody else have any feeling or idea whether this is true? Sorry for annoying:/